# 404 not found when navigating by route on symphony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

When I navigate on route I can't see my page web, I has just 404 not found

**config/routes/attributes.yaml**

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: attribute

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: attribute
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    #[Route('/lucky/number')]
    public function number(): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', [
            'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Twig**

```
{# templates/lucky/number.html.twig #}
<h1>Your lucky number is {{ number }}</h1>
```

Comment: Taking the time to make sure your question is readable (instead of relying on someone else to format it) will go a long way on stackoverflow.  Even better just searching for something like `symfony lucky number` will show dozens of previous questions as well as possible solutions.  In this case I would suggest looking at the [example in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#annotation-routes) to see what 'use' statement is missing.  And `bin/console debug:router` is quite useful.

Comment: "navigate on route" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are need .htaccess for rewrite url , install apache-patch , and it will take care of the config and adding htaccess.

**Install apache pack**

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Comment: In general Symfony developers tend to use the Symfony development server for developing.  It could be an Apache problem but just showing the composer statement without any real context is probably not all that helpful.  You have enough rep to comment.  Next time consider asking the poster what server they are using.

Comment: Hello Cerad , not everyone, me for example I use docker all the time, and I encountered this problem quite a few times, that's why I thought that's it, his problem exactly without talking much, OK, I'll take your note next time, thank you.

Comment: @iraouf Looks like you nailed it.  Congrats.  Still don't understand how it could be working without the route annotation use statement but that is okay.  Lots of things in this world I don't understand.

Comment: @Cerad I just saw that ,​​you're right, but following the question it's not **No route found** but rather 404 not found, but I was not sure .., I just wanted to be quick haha